# How to resolve moodle fresh installation issue mysql_full_unicode_support#File_format and mysql_full_unicode_support#Large_prefix

Tags: xampp, moodle

I am very new to Moodle. When i am trying to install this i got this issue(Please ref screenshot). 
[image]

Can any one help me regarding this?

Thank you in advance.
Omkar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is very common problem, people often face, even i did face too. When installing moodle latest 3.2+ it checks for enabled support for utf8mb4 charset in MySQL database. This doesn't come by default in MySQL. You need to set few parameters in mysql conf.

On Linux based systems you will want to alter my.cnf. This may be located in '/etc/mysql/'. Make the following alterations to my.cnf:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_large_prefix

character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

Post changing the values, restart mysql and the error should be fixed now.

Please refer below docuemnt

https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/MySQL_full_unicode_support

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#character-sets

Comment: What about Windows 10/11 ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue this helped me,
Go to phpmyadmin and copy the collation for information schema
In my case information_schema -> **utf8_general_ci**

[image]

Now go to htdocs/moodle/config.php and alter this section

```
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbsocket' => '',
  'dbcollation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
);
```

Note- here change only the dbcollation to 'utf8_general_ci'
and refresh the installation page this will solve both the errors

Comment: This is the solution if you do not want to mess the server installation to install Moodle.

Answer (score 3):

Please install (or access) phpmyadmin and execute SQL

```
set Global innodb_file_format = Barracuda
set Global innodb_file_per_table = 1
set Global innodb_large_prefix = "ON"
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you describe how this solves the questioner's problem (and why).

Comment: Awesome! This just worked out and allowed me (no ssh access) to solve the issue and continue installing

Comment: Is it safe to "assume" that innodb_file_format will always be Barracuda on all servers?

Is there anything you should check before running that "set Global innodb_file_format = Barracuda" command?