# Moodle 3.3.1 fresh install - Barracuda file format issue

Tags: installation, moodle, file-type

I am new to moodle and trying to install moodle 3.3.1 on my windows system, but after some steps it is showing some errors.

```
mysql_full_unicode_support#File_format: Your database has tables using Antelope as the file format. Full UTF-8 support in MySQL and MariaDB requires the Barracuda file format. Please convert the tables to the Barracuda file format.

mysql_full_unicode_support#Large_prefix: For full support of UTF-8 both MySQL and MariaDB require you to change your MySQL setting 'innodb_large_prefix' to 'ON'. See the documentation for further details.

site not https: It has been detected that your site is not secured using HTTPS. It is strongly recommended to migrate your site to HTTPS for increased security and improved integration with other systems.
```

please help me to resolve these errors. i am trying to install moodle on my windows system using xampp server. (localhost)

Comment: You can see this answer on how to fix it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44062153/how-to-resolve-moodle-fresh-installation-issue-mysql-full-unicode-supportfile-f/44116642#44116642

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be having 3 problems

**1. Your DB tables are in an earlier format and needs to be upgraded to Barracuda**

Moodle created an easy fix for the first problem, before going ahead with the upgrade, you can run the following script from your server, it will upgrade the problematic tables to the Barracuda format

The following command will give you the list of tables that needs to be updated

```
$ php /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/mysql_compressed_rows.php --list
```

Then run the fix

```
$ php /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/mysql_compressed_rows.php --fix
```

The following link will give you the steps and guide you through the update, the above scripts are from that link

https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Administration_via_command_line#Converting_InnoDB_tables_to_Barracuda

**2. You are having Unicode problems**

As of Moodle 3.2, utf8mb4 is used, some changes are required, these answers have been provided before but here they are just in case.

You will first need to edit your my.cnf file and add the following:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_large_prefix

character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

Restart your MySQL service and run the following script:

```
$ php /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/mysql_collation.php --collation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Then modify your config.php file:

```
$CFG->dboptions = array( 
… 
'dbcollation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', 
… 
);
```

The documentation can be found at the following location:

https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/MySQL_full_unicode_support

**3. Your site is not SSL**

To make your site SSL you will need to get a SSL certificate from a trusted store such as entrust.

Answer (score 1):

First search result in Google for the error message + "Moodle":

https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/MySQL_full_unicode_support

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you are trying to fix the error on a local installation using **xampp**.

This is what I did:

**first**

if you are using **xampp** on windows, then on your xampp control panel, locate the MYSQL **config** button and click to see the `my.ini` option, this is what is called `my.cnf` on other platforms.

[image]

**Second**

Copy the following text into the my.ini file.

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_large_prefix

character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

**Third**

restart the MYSQL and the error is gone!